# SP 2013: People Picker, One Way Domain Trust, Error finding people

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, people-picker, trusted-domain

We have a three tier server farm with a one way trust with the WFE on the resource domain. I installed FBA and FBAPack. Everything is working fine and I can add domain users to sites if I'm adding them from the app server.

However, when I try to use the "Share" option on the web, I get the error: Sorry, we're having trouble reaching the server.

I originally thought it might be a problem with alternate access mappings, but doing research it looks like it might be a problem with the People Picker itself.

I ran the following commands multiple times on both app and WFE:

stsadm –o setapppassword -password password1!

stsadm -o setproperty -url http://server:port/ -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "domain:mydomain.com, mydomain\myadminuser, password1!"

But when I run
stsadm -o getproperty -pn peoplepicker-onlysearchwithinsitecollection -url http://server:port

I get:
Property Exist="Yes" Value="no"

The only thing I can think of is that the exclamation point is causing the issue. I read that the password needs to have no special characters. Unfortunately, this violates the password group policy.

Any ideas?

Comment: You missed some words in the post. You get what after you run getproperty?

Comment: BTW, your steps are correct (I encountered same one-way trust issue before) but you may need to modify the permission on registry. Look at [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jorman/2011/02/16/people-picker-why-dont-you-trust-me/). If it helps please let me know and I will make it an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I think the formatting was treating the result like code. I edited, I get

Property Exist="Yes" Value="no"

Thanks for the article -- I was missing the Regedit on one of the servers. However, no change. I re-run commands and still get the error and the Property Exist result above.

Comment: I should clarify just in case -- I did not change the registry on the database server but on the app server and the WFE. I can run it on the DB server also if necessary.

Comment: Actually can't figure out how to change it on the DB server, the registry paths don't seem to line up. So I'm guessing that isn't necessary.

Comment: Does the "external" WFE have to have a clear path through firewall to the internal domain controller? Right now telnet is working from App server to internal DC but not from WFE to internal DC. This indicates that even the WFE needs the firewall ports open for the People Picker itself. (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3265414f-94fb-4b58-8d30-d23b36fb32be/people-picker-still-not-working-with-one-way-trust-after-adding-required-stsadm-commands?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

Comment: You don't need to change DB server registry as the key is stored at the server your run -setapppassword (you need to run Run SetAppPassword on EVERY machine in the farm but DB). I believe you need to open firewall between WFE and the one way domain DC.

Comment: Just another reminder, you may want to run the same command on your CA url as well. In my previous project, I forgot to do it and I cannot assign site collection admin using CA's people picker!